# How Jquery can get value in input field if using virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, virtual-keyboard, input-field

I have been asked to 3 times and no answer. 
please someone could tell me how jquery or javascript can get the value of the input form if typed by virtual keboard like Mottie Virtual Keyboard or JKeyboard (Made by Jquery). Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to detect change or you just want at any point to get the value?

Comment: any point dude. example i try to add maxlength in textarea, but it's not working if using virtual keyboard. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmfL6vgm/) , actually I just wanted to add a maxlength in the textarea, but does not work when using the virtual keyboard @metal03326

Comment: Getting the length doesn't have anything to do with the maxlength. Both keyboards use programmatic way of setting the value to the input, so maxlength won't work. If they don't support it, you can try to modify their code (ugly), request a ticked to add support for it (slow) or do some kind of external code to fix the issue (again ugly).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jkeyboard you can use on click at keyboard .
Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ashisha/okvo7rak/

```
  $('#keyboard').on("click", function (e) {
  alert($("#search_field").val())
  })
```

Comment: Okay, actually I want is to add attribute maxlength bro, can you teach me?

Comment: where on text area ?

Comment: on input field dude

Comment: I use jkeyboard for virtual keyboard

Comment: do you want to prevent typing after certain number ?

Comment: you can edit their code . in these lines

letters.on('click', function(){
      me.type((shift || capslock) ? $(this).text().toUpperCase() : $(this).text());
     })

I mean at all clicks

Comment: Where? Can you give me sample dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/okvo7rak/3/))

```
var $input = $('#search_field'),
  maxLength = 10;

$('#keyboard').jkeyboard({
  layout: "azeri",
  input: $input
});

$('.jkey').on("click", function(e) {
  var val = $input.val();
  if (val.length > maxLength) {
    $input.val(val.substring(0, maxLength));
  }
});
```